# Create an Array from sub arrays vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I have a string array A where I store some values for instance A(1) = "a,b,c" A(2)="1,2" etc. From that array I am creating subarrays using A(1).split(",") and I have

```
dim subArr1() as string = {"a","b","c"}
dim subArr2() as string = {"1","2"}
etc
```

Now, I want to create a new two-dimensional array

```
dim all()() as string = {subArr1, subArr2, ...}
```

The initial array is created dynamically and could be have 2, 5, or whatever number of items. So I could have any number of subArrays (subArrX)
Any idea how to deal with that? I am writing in vb.net 2013

Thank you

Comment: No, this {subArr1, subArr2, .... } I want to be created dynamically

Comment: look up 'jagged arrays'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this little LINQ query:

```
Dim A As String() = {"a,b,c", "1,2"}
Dim parts As IEnumerable(Of String()) = From str In A Select str.Split(","c)
Dim all()() As String = parts.ToArray()
```

Now the array contains two arrays, the first contains "a","b" and "c" and the second contains "1" and "2".